# Doppelte Pronomen in Relativsatz

Tags: grammar-identification, relative-clause, relative-pronoun

> Ihnen allen, die Sie außerhalb meiner Heil- und Pflegeanstalt ein verworrenes Leben führen müssen, Euch Freunden und allwöchentlichen Besuchern, die Ihr von meinem Papiervorrat nichts ahnt, stelle ich Oskars Großmutter mütterlicherseits her.
>
> (Günter Grass: *Die Blechtrommel*)

Der erste und zweite Relativsatz wird jeweils mit dem Pronomen "die" eingeleitet, welche für den Satz eigentlich ausreichend wären ("Ihnen allen, die außerhalb"). Wie nennt man das zweite Nomen "Sie" und "Ihr" in diesem Fall? Ist es rein stilistisch oder gibt es eine grammatikalische Begründung dafür?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In beiden Fällen handelt es sich um eine *Anrede*, die klar macht, dass der Relativsatz  nicht in der dritten Person (am Beispiel des zweiten Vorkommens:) die Besucher genauer spezifiziert, sondern um eine direkte Anrede der Freunde und Besucher und daher in der zweiten Person steht. (Es müsste sonst im zweiten Relativsatz *ahnen* heißen.)